# binary seach not returning value

Tags: python

the function is not returning anything i am not sure why but the program runs indefinitely

```
def binary_search(li,key):
    li.sort()
    #setting indexes
    low = 0
    high = len(li)-1 # becuse we know len is every item in the list
    while low <= high: # setting midpoint
        midpoint = (low-high)//2 # two divide sign makes return of operation interger not float
        if li[midpoint] == key:
            print('key found')
            return midpoint
        elif li[midpoint] < key:
            low = midpoint+1
        else:
            high = midpoint-1
    return -1

#always return -1 if key not found
li = [1,2, 3, 4, 5, 6 , 7, 8]
print(binary_search(li, 7))
```

Comment: Question `midpoint = (low-high)//2`.

Comment: I think OP forgot ```def binary_search(li, midpoint)```

Comment: @Sujay Was not forgotten - just lost in formatting. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

The `midpoint` is an index between `low` and `high`. To get it, you need to use

> `midpoint = (low + high) // 2`

and **NOT** this *(This is the reason your code runs indefinitely)*

> `midpoint = (low - high) // 2`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def binary_search(li, key):
    li.sort()
    low = 0
    high = len(li)-1 
    while low <= high:
        midpoint = (low+high)//2
        if li[midpoint] == key:
            print('key found')
            return midpoint
        elif li[midpoint] < key:
            low = midpoint+1
        else:
            high = midpoint-1
    return -1

li=[1,2, 3, 4, 5, 6 , 7, 8]
print(binary_search(li, 7))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to this simple binary search.

def search(li,key):

li.sort()

#setting indexes
low = 0

high = len(li)-1 #becuse we know len is every item in the list

while low <= high:#setting midpoint

```
  midpoint = (low+high)//2#two divide sign makes return of operation interger not float

  if li[midpoint] == key:

      print('key found')

      return midpoint

  elif li[midpoint] < key:

      low = midpoint+1

  else:

      high = midpoint  # it should be midpoint not midpoint-1
```

return -1

#always return -1 if key not found
li=[1,2, 3, 4, 5, 6 , 7, 8]

print(search(li, 5))